# Bootstrap 5 Hero

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am unable to figure out what classes should I add/remove to achieve the same image positioning as in the preview of the [Bootstrap Border hero with cropped image and shadows.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/heroes/)

My image doesn't sit on the edge of the hero and it looks even worst on mobile scale. Here is what my hero looks like now:

```
<div id="support" class="hero-donate container my-5">
    <div class="row p-4 pb-0 pe-lg-0 pt-lg-5 align-items-center rounded-3 border shadow-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-7 p-3 p-lg-5 pt-lg-3">
            <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold lh-1">Find out more and support our work</h1>
            <p class="lead">Text</p>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start mb-4 mb-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg px-4 me-md-2 fw-bold">DONATE</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg px-4">Volunteer</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1 p-0 overflow-hidden">
            <img class="rounded-lg-3 shadow-lg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608535002897-27b2aa592456?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="" width="75%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions for both

1. The image in example is an horizontal image hence it fits perfectly on the right end of div. Your image is vertical so apply this class : `float-end` on image tag.
2. For mobile view. Your code works fine only image alignment is distorted. for which apply `w-100` and `m-auto` to image tag. your updated image tag will look like :

   ```
   <img class="rounded-lg-3 shadow-lg float-end m-auto w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608535002897-27b2aa592456?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="" width="75%">
   ```

here is the working snippet

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="support" class="hero-donate container my-5">
    <div class="row p-4 pb-0 pe-lg-0 pt-lg-5 align-items-center rounded-3 border shadow-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-7 p-3 p-lg-5 pt-lg-3">
            <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold lh-1">Find out more and support our work</h1>
            <p class="lead">Text</p>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start mb-4 mb-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg px-4 me-md-2 fw-bold">DONATE</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg px-4">Volunteer</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1 p-0 overflow-hidden">
            <img class="rounded-lg-3 shadow-lg float-end m-auto w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608535002897-27b2aa592456?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8" alt="" width="75%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot! Now I've decreased the image size and added some padding to the bottom to get the same look as the bootstrap demo, but for some reason only the top image corners are rounded and the shadow doesn't show. Here is my img div: `<div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1 p-0 overflow-hidden"><img class="rounded-3 shadow-lg float-end w-100 m-auto pb-5" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608535002897-27b2aa592456?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="" width="55%"></div>`. Nothing else has been changed.

Comment: can you update this in your question. would be helpful

Comment: also @Eduard, bootstrap demo doesn't have padding bottom. If you remove it, the result looks same

Comment: If I don't add the padding bottom to the img, the image sits right on the edge of the hero.